# ¿Cómo crear varias copias de un fichero .txt con la misma información que el original?

Tags: c, archivo

Tengo un problema al realizar copias desde un fichero .txt en C. El programa copia perfectamente los archivos y los nombra, el problema es que solo copia el texto del archivo original a la ultima copia creada. Gracias de antemano espero puedan echarme una mano, gracias!

```c
int main ()
{

    int j=0, i=2;
    FILE *archivo1, *puntero[j];
    char nombrearchivo[50];
    char texto;

    printf("\tIngrese el nombre del archivo que desea copiar: \n");
    scanf("%s", &nombrearchivo);

    //Abriendo el archivo para su lectura
    archivo1 = fopen(nombrearchivo, "r");
    if(archivo1==NULL){
        printf("Error arbiendo el archivo.");
        exit(0);
    }

    //Creando las copias del archivo inicial "archivo1.txt"
    printf("Cuantas veces deseas copiar el archivo?: \n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    for(i=2; i<=j; i++){
        sprintf(puntero, "archivo%d.txt", i);
        puntero[j] = fopen(puntero, "w+");
    }

    //Copiando el texto a los demas archivos
     texto = fgetc(archivo1); 
     for(i=0; i>j; i++){
        while(texto!=EOF){
            fputc(texto, puntero[j]);
            texto = fgetc(archivo1);

         }
     }

    printf("Archivos copiados correctamente ;)");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenias varios problemas

```
 scanf("%s", &nombrearchivo);
```

recibe un puntero a cadena, y un array de char es un puntero a cadena(no hay necesidad del &).

```
 sprintf(puntero, "archivo%d.txt", i);
```

recibe como primer argumento un puntero a cadena y le estás pasando un puntero a un arreglo de FILE
tienes que declarar una string para ahí guardar el nombre que se requiere.

```
for(i=0; i>j; i++)
```

la condición i>j siempre sería falsa y se saltaría la copia.

EDIT: no había dado cuenta de lo que mencionaste. solo habrí el último archivo y pensé que todos los demás estarían igual :p

Otro error que tuvimos(sic) fue que en c no puedes declarar un arreglo de forma dinámica por lo que:

```
 int j = 0;
 FILE *puntero[j];
```

puntero siempre será de tamaño 0....

para arreglarlo y asignarlo de forma dinámica puedes utilizar malloc(declarada en sdtlib.h) para asignarlo de acuerdo con la cantidad de FILE requeridos i.e.

```
 scanf("%d", &j);
 puntero = (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*)*j);
```

no se te olvide liberar la memoria con 
     free(puntero);

Luego. En tus últimos loop tenías el error que estás moviendo en archivo1 y nunca lo reseteas para los próximos archivos. Es mejor(a mi parecer utilizar los loop al revés para que solo utilices el archivo en una ocasión)

también recuerda cerrar los archivos una vez ocupados. con

```
 fclose(NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO);
```

Así queda corregido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
        int j=0, i=2;
        FILE *archivo1, **puntero;
        char nombrearchivo[50];
        char texto;
        char string[1024];

        printf("\tIngrese el nombre del archivo que desea copiar: \n");
        scanf("%s", nombrearchivo);

        //Abriendo el archivo para su lectura
        archivo1 = fopen(nombrearchivo, "r");
        if(archivo1==NULL){
            printf("Error arbiendo el archivo.");
            exit(0);
        }

        //Creando las copias del archivo inicial "archivo1.txt"
        printf("Cuantas veces deseas copiar el archivo?: \n");
        scanf("%d", &j);

        puntero = (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*)*j);

        for(i=0; i<=j; i++){
            sprintf(string, "archivo%d.txt", i);
            puntero[i] = fopen(string, "w+");
        }

        //Copiando el texto a los demas archivos
         texto = fgetc(archivo1);
         while(texto!=EOF){
                for(i=0; i<=j; i++){
                        fputc(texto, puntero[i]);
                }
                texto = fgetc(archivo1);
         }


         //Cerrando archivos
         for(i=0; i != j; i++){
                fclose(puntero[i]);
         }

        free(puntero);
        printf("Archivos copiados correctamente ;)\n");

}
```

ahí está corregido pero intenta revisar la documentación de las funciones y lee bien los warnings te ayudan bastante a entender el problema.

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema, solo copia el texto del archivo original a la ultima copia, y no he logrado hacer que copie el texto del archivo original a absolutamente todas las copias creadas :(

Answer (score 1):

**1.-** El problema principal está en esta línea:

```c
int j=0, i=2;
FILE *archivo1, *puntero[j];
```

El identificador `puntero` es el nombre del *array* de punteros, sin embargo, le indicas un tamaño nulo (porque `j` es igual a `0`). Por lo tanto, no hay memoria asignada.

Se supone que cada elemento del *array* debe apuntar a un objeto de tipo `FILE`, pero como no sabemos cuantos objetos podemos tener, debemos usar memoria dinámica con [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
printf("Cuantas veces deseas copiar el archivo?: \n");
scanf("%d", &j);
//Esto reserva memoria para un array de punteros.
puntero = malloc(j * sizeof(FILE*));
```

Debemos tener en cuenta que el identificador `puntero` debe ser declarado como un puntero doble:

```c
FILE** puntero;
```

**Nota:** Un objeto a nivel de implementación es simplemente una **región de memoria**.

**2.-** Esta sentencia no está bien:

```c
for(i=2; i<=j; i++){
```

Para recorrer el *array* de punteros debemos de empezar a partir del índice `0` hasta `j - 1`.

**Corrección:**

```c
for(i=0; i< j; i++)
```

**3.-** Aquí tenemos otra sentencia errónea:

```c
sprintf(puntero, "archivo%d.txt", i);
```

El primer parámetro de la función [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) es un puntero a `char` y estás pasando un argumento de tipo `FILE`.

**Corrección:** Debes pasar un argumento de tipo `char*`.

**4.-** No puedes usar la variable `j` como índice en este caso:

```c
puntero[j] = fopen(puntero, "w+");
```

Ya que `j` es la cantidad de archivos donde se copiará la información original del otro archivo. Por lo tanto, debes usar la variable `i`.

**5.-** Por último, analicemos este bloque de código:

```c
//Copiando el texto a los demas archivos
texto = fgetc(archivo1); 
for(i=0; i>j; i++){
   while(texto!=EOF){
      fputc(texto, puntero[j]);
      texto = fgetc(archivo1);
   }
}
```

El código nunca funcionará por muchas razones:

- La condición de salida del bucle no es el adecuado. Debería ser `i < j`.
- No se debe usar la variable `j` como índice para poder acceder al *array* de puntero. Debería ser `i`.
- Aunque solucionemos las dos razones anteriores, solo copiará la información a un archivo. Porque `texto` siempre valdrá `EOF`, por ende, la condición del bucle `texto != EOF` nunca se cumplirá (esto solo pasará cuando intentemos copiar el contenido del archivo original a un segundo archivo). Así que cada vez que queramos leer el contenido del archivo original, deberemos de posicionar el puntero al principio del fichero y esto se logra con la función [rewind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/).

El código completo quedaría así con las correcciones vistas:

```c
int main ()
{

    int j, i;
    FILE *archivo1;
    FILE** puntero;
    char nombrearchivo[50];
    char otronombre[50];
    char texto;

    printf("\tIngrese el nombre del archivo que desea copiar: \n");
    scanf("%s", &nombrearchivo);

    //Abriendo el archivo para su lectura
    archivo1 = fopen(nombrearchivo, "r");
    if(archivo1==NULL){
        printf("Error arbiendo el archivo.");
        exit(0);
    }

    //Creando las copias del archivo inicial "archivo1.txt"
    printf("Cuantas veces deseas copiar el archivo?: \n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    puntero = malloc(j * sizeof(FILE*));
    if(puntero == NULL)
    {
        fclose(archivo1);
        printf("Error: No se pudo reservar memoria!");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(i=0; i< j; i++)
    {
        sprintf(otronombre, "archivo%d.txt", i);
        puntero[i] = fopen(otronombre, "w+");
    }

    for(i=0; i < j; i++)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            texto = fgetc(archivo1);
            if(texto == EOF) break;
            fputc(texto, puntero[i]);
        }
        //Posicionamos el puntero al principio del archivo para poder leer de nuevo el contenido del archivo original
        rewind(archivo1);
    }

    printf("Archivos copiados correctamente ;)");
    fclose(archivo1);
    //Debemos liberar la memoria que reservamos con malloc
    for(int i = 0; i != j; ++i)
        fclose(puntero[i]);
    free(puntero);
    return 0;
}
```

## Actualización:

En vez de usar `fgetc` podemos usar la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Este cambio mejora el rendimiento del algoritmo (claro, si los contenidos de cada archivo son grandes, de lo contrario, no habría una diferencia) porque no necesitamos leer un byte a la vez, sino, directamente leemos el bloque de bytes por cada línea que tenga el archivo, de este modo evitamos invocar a cada rato la función `fgetc`. Puedes encontrar más información en este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52131644/how-efficient-is-reading-a-file-one-byte-at-a-time-in-c).

El código quedaría así:

```c
//En vez de usar fputc, usamos fputs
for(i=0; i < j; i++)
{
     while(fgets(texto, sizeof(texto), archivo1))
        fputs(texto, puntero[i]);
     rewind(archivo1);
}
```

El único cambio que debemos hacer al código, es cambiar la declaración de la variable `texto`, ya que ahora no será de tipo `char`, sino un *array*.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
char texto[24];
```

Hay otra solución interesante que propuso @VictorJimenez99 y es cambiar los bucles al revés. En nuestro caso, mejoraría la velocidad porque no necesitamos invocar a la función `fgets` en cada iteración, sino, lo hacemos únicamente una vez y copiamos la línea leída en cualquier archivo. Esto también evita posicionar el puntero al principio del archivo.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
while(fgets(texto, sizeof(texto), archivo1))
    for(i=0; i < j; i++)
        fputs(texto, puntero[i]);
```

**Nota:** Las llaves de apertura y de cierre no hacen falta.

El código completo quedaría así:

```c
int main ()
{

    int j, i;
    FILE *archivo1;
    FILE** puntero;
    char nombrearchivo[50];
    char otronombre[50];
    char texto[24];

    printf("\tIngrese el nombre del archivo que desea copiar: \n");
    scanf("%s", &nombrearchivo);

    //Abriendo el archivo para su lectura
    archivo1 = fopen(nombrearchivo, "r");
    if(archivo1==NULL){
        printf("Error arbiendo el archivo.");
        exit(0);
    }

    //Creando las copias del archivo inicial "archivo1.txt"
    printf("Cuantas veces deseas copiar el archivo?: \n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    puntero = malloc(j * sizeof(FILE*));
    if(puntero == NULL)
    {
        fclose(archivo1);
        printf("Error: No se pudo reservar memoria!");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(i=0; i< j; i++)
    {
        sprintf(otronombre, "archivo%d.txt", i);
        puntero[i] = fopen(otronombre, "w+");
    }
    while(fgets(texto, sizeof(texto), archivo1))
        for(i=0; i < j; i++)
           fputs(texto, puntero[i]);
    printf("Archivos copiados correctamente ;)");
    fclose(archivo1);
    //Debemos liberar la memoria que reservamos con malloc
    for(int i = 0; i != j; ++i)
        fclose(puntero[i]);
    free(puntero);
    return 0;
}
```